# Selenium Serenity screen shots and movie delays and hangs the execution

Tags: java, selenium, file-upload, screenshot, serenity-bdd

We have a serenity framework, where by the screenshot and movie on failures are recording during the execution and is part of it and happens sequentially

i.e

1. Test Case Step1 - Pass
2. Test Case Step2 - Fail
3. Movie and Screenshot of failure for Step2
4. Test Case Step3 - Pass

The movie and the screenshot are uploaded to the FTP server which can cause slowness and sometimes it hangs if the network is slow

My question is:

1. Where is the best place to save these screenshot and movie? Will Netapp or box.com solve this? I believe not as they too depend on the network speed

OR

2. Can we use threads i.e the execution continues and we create another thread which handles screenshot creation or movie and does the upload, without impacting the current execution. But, i am not sure if serentity supports this

OR

3. Save the files in the local project directory and then upload them after the execution?

The execution results are very important and they need to be backed up

Answer (score 0):

Serenity BDD does not record movies, only screenshots; these take very little time if you configure them to only be take on failures, and these are taken and processed in a separate background thread (so saving them doesn't slow down the tests, though the WebDriver calls to retrieve the screenshot data will slow down the tests when screenshots are taken for every action). It doesn't currently support uploading the files anywhere though.

I presume the movies you refer to are done within your own code, so Serenity would have no control over these.

Screenshots are automatically recorded alongside the other test outcomes. The simplest approach would be to upload/sync them after the build has completed, or to simply store them on your CI server (which is what most shops seem to do).